# What happens to old links if I change my custom URL/subdomain?

Tags: branch.io

If I were to use a specific custom domain (e.g. `a.example.com`) for a while (creating links via the API, via the **Marketing** tab in the dashboard, etc.) and then change it later on (e.g. to `b.example.com`), is there defined behaviour for exactly what happens with the old `a.example.com` links that are out in the wild?

The docs [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/link-domain-subdomain/#setting-a-custom-link-domain) simply say:

> switching can cause significant problems with your existing links

What exactly are those problems? From a technical perspective, if `a.example.com` is **still** pointing to `custom.bnc.lt`, it should still be possible to identify what app that's for and what links it'll resolve to.

Just curious to know if anyone has any experience with this or a definitive answer to whether or not the "old" links will be broken after changing the custom domain and what "significant problems" may be encountered in doing so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Changing the subdomain will make the old links that use the previous subdomain **not work**. They will be redirected to a page with the message "This link does not exist or is expired...". I can't give a clear technical answer for this as I'm not aware of Branch's internal implementation. But my guess is, since Branch cannot intercept requests to the old subdomain links anymore (as you have configured a different subdomain in your Branch profile), it cannot add the Branch metadata to the response, making them useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: if you change your link domain, *all your existing links will stop working* and give errors.

While you're right that the CNAME record on the old domain is still pointing to `custom.bnc.lt` and will still forward traffic there, our backend performs a lookup to make sure the domain of the incoming link is affiliated with a known app in the system. If it doesn't find a match, we don't complete the link routing process.

As far as I know, we don't have any plans to support multiple domains for each Branch app configuration in the future. So the advice still holds!

> We recommend that you choose one domain or subdomain to use with Branch and stick with it, as switching can cause significant problems with your existing links.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Alex. That definitely clears it up!